# Is there an easy way to check for http resources when I am switching to https?

Tags: 6, media

The company I work for is going to be switching to serving everything over https. This means that all referenced images/scripts/etc. need to also be server over https. Is there a way to see what links/references and such I will need to manually fix?

Answer (score 2):

Saint Mary's College in Notre Dame, IN has developed a script to look through the node_revisions table and help you visualize the references. You will likely have to adapt what they have written to fit your situation, but you can check it out [on github](https://github.com/Saint-Marys-College/drupal-href-src-viewer).